# Use error message as label after form submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have this form which I would like to use for user's password reset:

HTML code:

```
<form class="grid-wrapper" #f="ngForm" *ngIf="stepOne">

  <div class="form-group first-row">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="user.name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group second-row">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text"
           name="email"
           class="form-control"
           email required
           [(ngModel)]="user.email"
           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': nameEmailMismatch || notFound }">
    <div class="invalid-feedback-custom">
      <div *ngIf="nameEmailMismatch">Provided email doesn't belong to current user</div>
      <div *ngIf="notFound">User not found</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-row third-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.invalid || loading" (click)="submit()">Reset</button>
  </div>

</form>

<div *ngIf="stepTwo">

  <div>
    <h2>Password reset link has been sent to your email</h2>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="complete" *ngIf="stepFour">
  <p>
    Your password has been reset
  </p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  ........
})
export class ResetPasswordNewComponent implements OnInit {

  user: UserReset = new UserReset(null, null, null, null, null, null);

  stepOne = true;
  stepTwo = false;

  loading = false;

  nameEmailMismatch = false;
  notFound = false;

  constructor(private resetService: PasswordResetService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.nameEmailMismatch = false;
    this.notFound = false;

    this.resetService.requestReset(this.user).subscribe(user => {
        this.stepOne = false;
        this.stepTwo = true;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      error => this.handleError(error));
  }

  handleError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.loading = false;
    switch (error.error) {
      case 'NAME_AND_EMAIL_MISMATCH':
        this.nameEmailMismatch = true;
        break;
    }

    switch (error.status) {
      case 404:
        this.notFound = true;
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

How I can display messages when form is submitted and for example user or password is not found? Currently the solution is to use variable with true and false. Is there other solution for this for example label which is used after form submit?

Comment: You can append a div with error message after the input in handleError function but I think the way you used is better, and you do not need multi variables and divs to control which message show, just one bool to control if error message show, and a {{errorMessage}} thing in a single div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reactiveform`, this form validation provide `setError('custom-erro',true/false)` and you can set on your form submit call. let me know if you need more clear vision.

Comment: Can you paste code example please from my code, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttwlhv

Comment: I made a fork with my code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5lmt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Can you update please the code?

Answer (score 0):

You case the `submitted` property of `ngForm` which will be true if the form has been submitted.

```
  <div class="invalid-feedback-custom" *ngIf="f.submitted"> <!-- Check for form submission -->
      <div *ngIf="nameEmailMismatch">Provided email doesn't belong to current user</div>
      <div *ngIf="notFound">User not found</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show me a solution with reactive forms using my code, please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5lmt3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts